# Composition with long cycle

Tags: group-theory

Pick a random element $\sigma$ in $S_n$ of cycle length $n$.

Is it true that for any random element $\tau$ in $S_n$ either both $\tau\circ\sigma$ and $\sigma\circ\tau$ are cycles of length $n$ or both are non-cycles of length $n$?

Comment: This isn't always true, consider $\tau = \sigma^{-1}$ (unless you define the length differently).

Comment: @JamesMitchell: We are given that $\sigma$ has cycle length $n$, so it cannot be the identity.

Comment: @JamesMitchell: Whether or not you define cycle length here as the minimum cycle, $t=\sigma^{-1}$ works fine. $(\tau \circ \sigma)^n=(\sigma \circ \tau )^n=$identity.  In either case, the two expressions either cycle with length $n$ or neither one does.

Comment: Right I totally misread the question.

Comment: The point is that $\sigma \circ \tau$ and $\tau \circ \sigma$ are *conjugate* in $S_n$, so they always have the same cycle types.

Comment: Given $n$-length cycle $\sigma\in S_n$ is there always a $\tau\in S_n$ such that $\tau\circ\sigma\circ\tau^{-1}$ is a cyclic shift? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580857/conjugating-long-cycles-to-make-shift-permutation

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to use that $\sigma$ has cycle length $n$.  Presuming that you define cycle length as the minimum length of a cycle and letting $e$ be the identity element of your group, let $m$ be the cycle length of $\tau \circ \sigma$.  Then $(\tau \circ \sigma)^m=e$ and for $k \lt m,\ (\tau \circ \sigma)^k \neq e$  Then $\tau^{-1} (\tau \circ \sigma)^m \tau=e=(\sigma \circ \tau)^m$, and we can make the same argument for $k \lt m$, so the cycle lengths are the same (and therefore are either both $n$ or neither is $n$)